# Handling nested asynchronous functions to return one final result

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express, bcrypt

In my backend server which runs on express I have:

```
app.post("/login", async(req, res) => {
    try {
        const { username, password } = req.body;
        let result = await checkCredentials(username, password)
        console.log("result of checkCredentials:", result);
        res.json(result);
        
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
});
```

on post, the function `checkCredentials` get's called

```
const checkCredentials = async (clientUsername, clientPassword) => {
    try {
        const dbUsernameObj = await pool.query("SELECT varol_users_dealer_username FROM varol_users_dealers_credentials WHERE varol_users_dealer_username = $1", [clientUsername]);
        const dbUsername = dbUsernameObj.rows[0]?.varol_users_dealer_username
        const dbHashObj = await pool.query("SELECT varol_users_dealer_hash FROM varol_users_dealers_credentials WHERE varol_users_dealer_username = $1", [clientUsername])
        const dbHash = dbHashObj.rows[0]?.varol_users_dealer_hash

       // the 4 lines above are SQL queries that get the respective values, if they exist, if not they're undefined.


        if (dbUsername === clientUsername) {
            bcrypt.compare(clientPassword, dbHash, function(err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err)
                }
                return result
            }); 
        } else {
            return false
        }
        
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

The problem with this code is, if I supply the right combination of username and password, when `checkCredentials` logs, it returns undefined. if my password is wrong, it also returns undefined.

But when my username is wrong, it returns false.

I believe the issue lays in promise chaining, since `bcrypt.hash` returns another promise, and the value of `checkCredentials` get's logged before `bcrypt` finishes.

How can I solve this issue? many thanks.

Comment: "... since bcrypt.hash returns another promise ..." your code doesn't use/call `bcrypt.hash`

Comment: `return await bcrypt.compare(clientPassword, dbHash);`

Comment: You know that a SELECT statement can return more than one column at a time, right? `const dbUsernameObj = pool.query("SELECT varol_users_dealer_username, varol_users_dealer_hash FROM varol_users_dealers_credentials WHERE varol_users_dealer_username = $1", [clientUsername]);` `const dbHashObj = dbUsernameObj;`

Comment: @Thomas Thank you for your answer. My code does use/call bcrypt.compare. And unfortunately adding return await on bcrypt.compare doesn't work because the function itself is asynchronous. Is there any possible answer?

Comment: [`bcrypt.compare()` returns a Promise](https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js#with-promises). Are you using an older version of bcrypt?

Answer (score -1):

Try returning a promise

```
const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        if (dbUsername === clientUsername) {
            bcrypt.compare(clientPassword, dbHash, function(err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err)
                }
                resolve(result)
            }); 
        } else {
            resolve(false)
        }
})
return promise
```

Comment: [What is the explicit promise construction antipattern and how do I avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it). And [`bcrypt.compare()` returns a Promise](https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js#with-promises)